# chat implementation in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chat, whatsapp

I currently have a parent component called chat and two child component named sidebar(consisting of user list) and conversation detail(consisting of chat with each user)..
the functionality i want is if i click on any user present in sidebar i want the chat to open of that user on right side just like in WhatsApp web.. below is a small code of structuring of my components

Chat component(parent component)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
        <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
    </div>

    <div class="col-7">
        <app-conversation-detail></app-conversation-detail>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question doesn't show enough research effort, i advise you to check the Angular documentation and read about data and logic interaction between components (data binding).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the state in the parent component itself and just pass the data to your `sidebar` and `conversation-detail` via `@Input()`.

For starters, you could do something like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
        <app-sidebar [convoList]="convoList" (userSelected)="selectUser($event)"></app-sidebar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7">
        <app-conversation-detail [conversation]="conversation">
        </app-conversation-detail>
    </div>
</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  selectedUser = null;
  conversation = null;
  convoList = [];

  constructor(private conversationService: ConversationService) {}

  selectUser(user: string) {
    this.selectedUser = user;
    this.conversation = this.getConversationsOfUser(user);
  }

  getConversationsOfUser(user: string) {
    return this.conversationService.getConversationOfUser(user);
  }
}
```

You can also use a more reactive approach by using Observables.